# Sql Server - Counting partitions with Ranking functions

Tags: sql-server, ranking-functions

Consider the following sample data:

```
Name    Email  RowRank   PartitionRank
----    -----  -------   -------------
a1      e1      1         1
a1      e1      2         1
a2      e2      1         2
a2      e2      2         2
a2      e2      3         2
```

I am trying to write a query which partitions the data by Name + Email, then gives me index of a row in each partition and the number of partition itself (the last 2 columns list the expected output).

I have been trying with various queries, producing RowRank is easy with ROW_NUMBER, however I am unable to produce partition rank using any of the 4 ranking functions (NTILE, RANK, DENSE_RANK or ROW_RANK). I am sure this should be possible, but can't get onto it myself.

Here's a sample query:

```
SELECT Name, Email,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Email ORDER BY Email, DisplayName) AS RowRank,
        NTILE(1) OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Email ORDER BY Email, DisplayName) AS PartitionRank
FROM Zone.MyTable
```

Can someone please help me get the partition rank correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a DENSE_RANK() over the whole output (no partitioning)

```
SELECT Name, Email,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name, Email ORDER BY Email, DisplayName) AS RowRank,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Name, Email) AS PartitionRank
FROM Zone.MyTable
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
select *
  , RowRank = row_number() over (partition by Name order by Email)
  , PartitionRank = dense_rank() over (order by Name)
from MyTable
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bd7f5/4).

Comment: Thanks Ian, unfortunately only one reply can be marked as an answer :(

Answer (score 0):

```
select * ,row_number() over (order by Salary desc) as [Row_number],rank() over (order by Salary desc) as [Rank],dense_rank() over (order by Salary desc) as [Dense_rank],ntile(3) over (order by Salary desc) as [Ntile] from Employee
```

Check example in the URL given below

http://www.freshcodehub.com/Article/50/implement-ranking-functions-in-sql-server